# How can I use my own model class in the Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

I wrote a DB class and I want to create my own model class in the Zend Framework. My own model extends from PDO and it automatically creates a query to work with the database.
How can I use my own model class in the Zend Framework?

Comment: load your model file and create new instance of your model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you put your class in the  `models/Myclass.php` file then your class would look something like this:-

```
class Application_Model_Myclass
{
    //all my class stuff goes here
}
```

You could then use it in your controller or in another model like this:-

```
$myclass = new Application_Model_Myclass();
```

There is more information on [Zend Framework naming conventions in the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework has no official model support, so you don't need to do anything special. As long as your model has methods for saving, updating, and deleting, you can use it as you would any other model.

You won't have access to any of the Zend Framework "automagic", such as automatically populating fields. You'll have to expose public methods for getting and setting all of your fields.